# make inference rule for files in a folder

Tags: makefile, inference

I use GNU make, I want my source files and object files to be in different folders.

As a first step, I want the source files at the root of my project folder, and the object files in a subfolder (say `Debug/`).

The inference rule would be:

```
.ss.obj:
    echo Assembling $*.ss...
    $(ASSEMBLY) $(2210_ASSEMBLY_FLAGS) $*.ss -o Debug\$*.obj
```

but in that case, make rebuilds all files all the time, since there are no .obj in the root folder.

Is there a way to include a folder for the target in the line `.ss.obj`?

I also tried:

```
$(OBJS_WITH_PATH):$(SRC)    
    echo Assembling $<...
    $(ASSEMBLY) $(ASSEMBLY_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

with `$(SRC)` as a list of all my sources, `$(OBJS_WITH_PATH)` built that way:

```
OBJS_WITH_PATH = $(patsubst %.ss,Debug\\%.obj,$(SRC))
```

but that builds a dependency on all source files for all object files.

What I would like is to modify the inference rule I wrote first, to take `Debug/*.obj` files. What it says now is `no rule to make target Debug/asdfasdf.obj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pattern rules:

```
Debug/%.obj : %.ss
```